# Unary predicate for finite number of values

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, provability, automated-theorem-proving

I am working with automated prover. I am creating a theory, where an unary predicate PR should be true just for several constants, false otherwise. I made following axioms:

```
PR(const1).
PR(const2). 
...
PR(constK).
```

I want to define it such that I can prove not(PR(T)) for every term T different from const1 ... constK. It can not be proven from the axioms above. How should I define PR?

I also tried to add the axiom below, still does not help.

```
forall x  (  PR(x)  ->   x = const1  V  ...  V  x = constK  ).
```

To make it more clear, I need to define PR in a way, such that adding a new axiom PR(C) with a new constant would make my theory inconsistent. Adding PR(C) now just adds a new consistent axiom.  I know I can add an axiom  not(PR(C)) for each constant C, but there are too many constants in my theory.

Comment: Why does the formula you mention at the end not help? In conjunction with the others, it states that $PR$ holds of $x$ exactly when $x$ is one of your constants.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with a proof process. It uses inference ruels (resolution etc.) to prove it syntactically. I need to define it in the way, when syntactic proof would exist.

Comment: Change the conditional statement to a biconditional: forall x (P(x) <-> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this without all other constants appearing in some axiom. For a constant that doesn't appear in an axiom, there's nothing to keep it from being equal to one of the constants for which $PR$ is true. So you'll need something like $\neg PR(c)$ or $c\ne\text{const1}\land c\ne\text{const2}\land\ldots$ for every other constant $c$. Even if you come up with something that you prefer to $\neg PR(c)$, it'll have to mention each other constant at least once.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have about 10 different constants and about 1000 values created by applying f(a,b) on constants (I can define it recursively). My theory should have a finite model, it should be decidable. What would be an elegant definition of PR(c) just on few terms, so it can be proven false on other terms?

Comment: @IvanKuckir: I don't know about the finite model and decidability part, but the easiest way to prove $PR(c)$ false on all terms other than the constants would seem to be $\forall_{a,b}\neg PR(f(a,b))$?

Comment: OK, I got it. I somehow forgot, that different constant symbols can be mapped to the same item in the model.

Comment: can you take a look at this? :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738944/defining-sets-of-elements

Comment: can you take a look at this? :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743901/why-is-my-formula-contradicting