# The right way of defining a predicate

Tags: predicate-logic, provability, automated-theorem-proving

My theory contains a definition of lists: L(H,T) is a list, H is the first element (head), T is the list of remaining elements (tail), nil is empty list. So [A,B,C]  = L(A,L(B,L(C,nil))). I defined equality for lists:

```
all X,Y : not(nil = L(X,Y)) ).
all Xh,Xt,Yh,Yt : (  L(Xh,Xt) = L(Yh,Yt)  <=>  ( Xh=Yh & Xt=Yt) ) ).
```

I also have a constant "c". I want to define a predicate TR(S,A,T), which should be true iff A is a list starting with "c":

```
all S,A,T,Tail : (  TR(S,A,T) <=> A=L(c,Tail) ).
```

But this axiom brings contradiction into my theory. What is the right way of defining TR?

Comment: How do you mean, this axiom brings contradiction into your theory? Have you found a contradiction? If so, what is it?

Comment: The contradiction is, that  `all S,A,T,Tail : (  TR(S,A,T) <=> A=L(c,Tail) )` implies  `all S,A,T,Tail : (  TR(S,A,T) => A=L(c,Tail) )`  , which implies that `all S,A,T : (  TR(S,A,T) => all Tail : A=L(c,Tail) )`   And `all Tail : A=L(c,Tail)`  can not be true for any A.

Comment: I think I should use `all S,A,T : (  TR(S,A,T) <=> exists Tail : A=L(c,Tail) ).`

Comment: That's not a contradiction, that just means that `TR(S,A,T)` can never be true. But that's not what you wanted, so yes, you should use the above.

Comment: I am sorry for expressing my self incorrectly. I was able to prove, that `TR(S,A,T) => not(S=S)`, TR(S,A,T) implies contradiction.